# String index in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I want to use a specific string in addition to a number to the index of array,

I make like this

```
var array = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){
    array = addToArray();
    console.log("array size " + array.length);
});

function addToArray(){
    var i = 0;
    var tmpArray = new Array();
    while(i<10){
        if(i>9){
            addToArray();
            i++;
        }
        else{
            tmpArray["elem"+i] = "i";
            console.log(tmpArray["elem"+i]); // It prints out!!!
            i++;
        }
    }
    console.debug(tmpArray);

    return tmpArray;
}
```

​
When I print out the tmpArray, it's empty. Also the size is 0. When I remove the "elem" from the index of the array, it works properly. What should I do?

Here's a real example: http://jsfiddle.net/dfg3x/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have string array keys like PHP & some other languages. What you have done is to add a property named `elem + i` to the `tmpArray` object. It doesn't affect the array's `.length` property, even though the property is there and accessible, and it is *not* accessible via array methods like `.pop(), .shift()`

Perhaps instead you should declare `tmpArray` as an object literal since you don't appear to be using it with any numeric keys.

```
function addToArray() {
    var i = 0;
    // Make an object literal
    var tmpObj = {};
    while(i<10) {
       if(i>9) {
          addToArray();
          i++;
       }
       else {
          tmpObj["elem"+i] = "i";
          console.log(tmpObj["elem"+i]); //it prints out !!!
          i++;
       }
    }
    console.debug(tmpObj );

    return tmpObj ;
}
```